# Rails deployment on Site5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano, shared-hosting

I'm trying to deploy my Rails 3 application to a Site 5 shared hosting using capistrano. I've encountered many little problems and solved them step by step, but this one is getting me nuts:
When `bundle install` is executed by capistrano, i'm getting asked for a password, so I guess that bundle is trying to install my app gems globally in the shared hosting, root password then. This is capistrano asking me for root password, when I execute `cap deploy:migrations`:

```
triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * executing `bundle_install'
  * executing "cd /home/domain/public_html/releases/20110406100442 && bundle install"
    servers: ["domain.com"]
    [domain.com] executing command
 ** [out :: domain.com] Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
 ** [out :: domain.com] Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system:
```

I changed the `.gemrc` file to include my local gems path, so I can install gems connected to the server via ssh. That works perfectly... I also changed the `GEM_PATH` value in my deploy.rb file, but it still doesn't work:

```
default_environment['GEM_PATH']='/home/domain/.gem:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8'
```

Any ideas? Getting nuts over here...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try bundle install --deployment